# AirPlay button on custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

4.3 finally :) I am searching right now how to add air play button to custom view. I have MPMoviePlayer that load movie. I disabled standard controls and added overlay view with my custom play, pause, stop, volume buttons.
If anybody know how to add button that will be air play please share knowledge?
I cant't find what notification to send, what to listen...:(

Comment: Finally found a way to do it. I've edited my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT** It seems I've been misguided in my previous answer because the device was not running the released version iOS 4.3.

There is a way to provide the *AirPlay button* on a custom interface.
Use a `MPVolumeView` and add it to your view hierarchy

```
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView =
[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: overlayView.bounds];
[overlayView addSubview: myVolumeView];
[myVolumeView release];
```

The `MPVolumeView` provides the volume slider and the route button (see image below). But I don't think it's possible to only display the button.

[image: MPVolumeView at the bottom]

Comment: I don't have AppleTV with me now but I will test it as soon as I can. I can't wait to see this feature :) There is explanation also here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html about VolumeView. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work for me. the button is shown, but doesn't do anything when I click AppleTV button. Any ideas?

Comment: Remember to add 'MediaPlayer.framework' in Project's Build Phases under 'Link Binary With Libraries' section. Otherwise you will see just blank view.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is an old question. But it is possible to just show the button without the slider by using - [MPVolumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];

Comment: if you don't have an AppleTV, you should be able to use apps like AirServer on a mac?

Answer (score 40):

If you want just the AirPlay button without the volume slider follow the instructions in Jilouc's answer and then set the following properties on the myVolumeView:

```
[myVolumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
[myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
```

That will hide the volume slider but keep the route button.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay/EnrichYourAppforAirPlay.html) Apple also includes a snippet for that:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init] ;
[volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
[volumeView sizeToFit];
[view addSubview:volumeView];
```