# AVAudioRecorder and AirPlay Mirrioring

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avaudiorecorder, airplay

When I have an AVAudioRecorder Session active - (when I'm recording audio) I can't activate AirPlay mirroring on the device. Airplay mirroring just deactivates while the app is running and switches it back on when the app exits. This post seems to suggest [there is no way around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892022/avaudioplayer-and-airplay-possible).

My thoughts are to try:

- using a lower level recording framework
- <s>or [outputting a separate window to external display](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/WindowAndScreenGuide/UsingExternalDisplay/UsingExternalDisplay.html), rather than mirroring</s> (I've tried this, it doesn't work).

Is there another way around this, or do you know whether either of these methods are known to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AudioQueue to record (like Apple's Sample Code [Speak Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html)) rather than the AVRecorder works. A bit more work to implement, but recording continues on or off Airplay mirroring.

Comment: The Speak Here example doesn't seem to work with Airplay, it just offers two options for playback: the iPhone (ear) or iPhone external speaker. Did you modify it to work with Airplay?

Comment: I don't think so. If you fire up airplay and connect it to an external device while speak here is playing then it'll work fine. AFAIK there isn't a way to specify an airplay output without user intervention.