# Titanium: Airplay button for custom video player

Tags: ios, titanium

I have built a custom video player in Titanium. Everything works on it currently, however, I need to implement the `AirPlay` button back in. Using native objective-c, I see it is possible to do this using a the `MPVolumeView` according to this thread: [AirPlay button on custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311373/airplay-button-on-custom-view)

That is great, if I was coding in objective-c, but that isn't the case. Does anyone have any idea how I can implement this feature through titanium?

Comment: Hey Ronnie, did you have a look at https://github.com/blaart/Titanium-tvout-module ? It has not been maintained for two years, but maybe it is still working...

Comment: @mwfire I did take a look at it, however, that module requires a cable between the device and a TV. At least that is according to this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggAWnQ8dmpM

Comment: Yes, I found that strange too, but I have read some posts saying they use it to AirPlay stuff...